# How to set cookie on a specific page with a parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to use this code to set my cookie

```
function setChosen($chosen) {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['ws-chosen'])) {
        setcookie('ws-chosen', $chosen, strtotime('1 days')); 
    }
}
```

I want it to be called on a specific page like:

```
setChosen($chosenitem);
```

I am using wordpress and this doesnt work unless I hook it to init on functions.php

```
add_action('init','setChosen');
```

But I need to pass on a parameter as a value for the cookie from a specific page;

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out: [Place a cookie when a specific page has been viewed?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56507/place-a-cookie-when-a-specific-page-has-been-viewed)

You can put logic in the `functions.php` file to detect you are on the page you want and set your cookie values accordingly.